# What type of brown mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

What mushroom is this? Maybe some type of Armillaria?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, where in the world is this photo located?

Comment: Hello, it's in Austria, close to Kufstein.

Comment: The ID is incomplete because we can't see the profile of the gills and the stalk.

Comment: I added another image